# How to grep for the whole string after a word in the string is matched

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have this

> -Xmx10240m -Xms10240m -verbose:gc -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=3600 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xloggc:/www/logs/jboss/macys-navapp_master_prod_cellA_m01/gc-log.txt -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/www/logs/heapdump/navapp_master_prod_cellA__m01/navapp_master_prod_cellA_m01.hprof -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dclient.encoding.override=ISO-8859-1 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.apache.jasper.Constants.USE_INSTANCE_MANAGER_FOR_TAGS=false -Dorg.apache.jasper.Constants.USE_INSTANCE_MANAGER -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.USE_POOL=false -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -XX:NewSize=3072m -XX:MaxNewSize=3072m -agentpath:/www/a/apps/dynatrace/dt.so=name=server1_ProdCellA_master_m1,server=ct_collector:9998 -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dsdp.configuration.home=/www/apps/properties -XX:+UseLargePages -Dzookeeper.sasl.client=false

I want to be able to grep this whole string after i matched "-agentpath" "-agentpath:/www/a/apps/dynatrace/dt.so=name=server1_ProdCellA_master_m1,server=ct_collector:9998"

This is the current command i'm working with but it's not working "cat cached_java_opts | awk '/-agentpath/ {print $(NF)}'"

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` solution:

```
awk -F'-agentpath:' '{split($2,a," ") ;print FS a[1]}' infile
-agentpath:/www/a/apps/dynatrace/dt.so=name=server1_ProdCellA_master_m1,server=ct_collector:9998
```

`grep` : more or less,same as already answered.

```
grep -oP '\-agentpath:.*?\s' infile
-agentpath:/www/a/apps/dynatrace/dt.so=name=server1_ProdCellA_master_m1,server=ct_collector:9998
```

Answer (score 1):

launch `grep` like this:

```
grep -o '\-agentpath[^ ]*' yourfile
```

The `-o` option prints only the matching pattern (not the matching line). Since the pattern is configured to expand until the first space, you'll get the entire argument (this works because it is not the last argument of the command line). Maybe it could be improved with `grep -oE '\-agentpath([^ ]*|.*$)'`

Comment: Thanks you for ur reply, but seem like "-agenth" it think these are more grep options becuase of "-", even though I have put "-" around it

Comment: append escape char like grep -o '\-agentpath[^ ]*' yourfile

Comment: sorry, could not test it here because my grep at work doesn't have the `-o` option (it's rather recent). Edited. Now understands the `-agentname`. @muzido thanks for correcting that!

Comment: That work I forgot about the escaping too lolz , thank you very much